# How do I scale a dichotomous variable for a prior in brms?

Tags: r, bayesian, mixed-model

Lets say that I am predicting reaction time.

Every subject responds to 100 trials of different flashes of light.

I have two predictors: one is continuous (e.g., brightness of the light) and one is categorical (e.g., colour of the light: blue vs red). The categorical variable is sum coded (i.e., -.5 and .5) These are just made up examples btw.

Let's say I want to use the same generic prior on both fixed effects: a normal distribution centred at 0 with an sd of 1. How do I scale the prior to these different kinds of predictors?

For the continuous predictor I know that I would use the sd of the brightness distribution and multiply that by the sd of my prior distribution.

But what do I do for my dichotomous predictor?